# PHP Codeigniter-Uninitialized string offset:

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to upload excel file get the value and save it to database, the weird thing is when my excel file has 13 rows and up then the error Uninitialized Offset is occurred.

```
if (isset($dataRow)) {  
            foreach($dataRow as $key => $dataVal)   :

                foreach($dataVal as $key => $dataSume)  
                    $fArray = $dataSume;
                    $y =  count ($dataSume); 

                        for($x=0; $x < 1; $x++ ){
                            if ( isset($fArray) ){
                                $this->varOrder->addCount($fArray[0],$fArray[1],$fArray[2],$fArray[3],$fArray[4],$fArray[5],$fArray[6],$fArray[7],$fArray[8],$flag2);
                            }
                        }
                endforeach;
```

this is the value of $dataRow array.

```
array(12) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(123) [2]=> string(5) "apple" [3]=> float(45) [4]=> string(2) "pc" [5]=> string(5) "A1011" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42110) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(2) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(20) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1016" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(5) "chico" [3]=> float(7) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "ads" } } [4]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(125) [2]=> string(9) "pineapple" [3]=> float(8) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1013" [6]=> float(1102) [7]=> float(42112) [8]=> string(3) "ads" } } [5]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(123) [2]=> string(5) "apple" [3]=> float(45) [4]=> string(2) "pc" [5]=> string(5) "A1011" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42110) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } [6]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(2) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } [7]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(20) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1016" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } [8]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(5) "chico" [3]=> float(7) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "ads" } } [9]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(125) [2]=> string(9) "pineapple" [3]=> float(8) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1013" [6]=> float(1102) [7]=> float(42112) [8]=> string(3) "ads" } } [10]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(123) [2]=> string(5) "apple" [3]=> float(45) [4]=> string(2) "pc" [5]=> string(5) "A1011" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42110) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } [11]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(2) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } }
```

this is the only value that system get when the number of rows is 13.

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(2) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(4) "a1a1" } }
```

I tried to add `if ( isset($fArray) )` before the for loop to catch the offset, but still didn't work.

is this problem is on my foreach or for loop?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please output the contents of `var_dump` or `print_r` *indented*. It's impossible to look through one long string for structure like this. All you have to do is output a `<pre>` element beforehand or just look at the source instead of the generated HTML page. Also, why are you using a `for` loop? You're also using a mix of `{}` and `foreach():` meaning the code isn't executing as you think.

Comment: just guessing but Check if there is any extra spaces in ur excel at the end!! both vertically and horizontally

Comment: @Varshaan still offset error occured. when I tried get the $dataVal its only get the last cell value in the excel file.

Comment: @h2ooooooo the value only get the last cell value.

Comment: @gerXpaulLlames Because, as explained, when you use `foreach($dataVal as $key => $dataSume)  $fArray = $dataSume;` you're immediatly ending your for loop. Hence `dataSume` will ALWAYS be the last item in the array as the only contents of the foreach is `$fArray = $dataSume;`. Just because you indent your code doesn't mean PHP knows what you mean when you're ignoring the use of brackets (`{}`) and/or colons (`:`). Do you _mean_ it to only take the last value? I'd be very confused if I was another developer reading this code.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I add {} on foreach, But i get error Uninitialized string offset: 8

Comment: are u using csv format?

Comment: @Varshaan excel format (.xls or .xlsx)

Comment: did u try $dataVal[0] instead of reiterating through?

Comment: @Varshaan I already try $dataVal, Im only getting the last row in the excel file.

Comment: Am sorry for last comment - please check if your file pointer is reset - maybe its still pointing to 12th record

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101572/discussion-between-gerxpaul-llames-and-varshaan).